# How to bind current value of property image in ViewModel with tag img (Knockout.js)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How to bind current value of property image in ViewModel with tag img (Knockout.js)? I want to see current value (for example, 'sort_down.png'), but attribute src of image tag don't change ('no_sort.png'). Help me to fix problem in this code. Also I used Knockout method ko.computed, but that code don't work correctly.

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src: image}"></p>
<div data-bind="click: sortTableByName"></div>

function ViewModel() {

                var self = this;

                self.articles = ko.observableArray(model);

                self.asc_sort_string = ko.observable(false);
                self.desc_sort_string = ko.observable(false);

                self.image = ko.observable('no_sort.png');

                self.update = function(){
                    // ... code
                };

                self.sortTableByName = function(){
                    if (self.desc_sort_string == false) {
                       self.asc_sort_string = false;
                       self.desc_sort_string = true;
                       self.image = 'sort_down.png';
                    }else{
                       self.asc_sort_string = true;
                       self.desc_sort_string = false;
                       self.image = 'sort_up.png';
                    }
                };


            };

            var viewModel = new ViewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            viewModel.update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your properties as observables, and you need to update them accordingly.

```
self.sortTableByName = function(){
    if (self.desc_sort_string() == false) {
       self.asc_sort_string(false);
       self.desc_sort_string(true);
       self.image('sort_down.png');
    }else{
       self.asc_sort_string(true);
       self.desc_sort_string(false);
       self.image('sort_up.png');
    }
};
```

Comment: For `ko.computed` try to look at this example http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html